# How could I install Ubuntu in UEFI mode?

Tags: installation, boot, uefi

When I try to boot the usb flash drive the text that appears is garbled.It works in legacy mode but not in UEFI.

How could I install Ubuntu in UEFI mode ?

This is how the bootscreen looks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, are you saying that this is what happens *after* you select the boot option in GRUB, or that GRUB itself looks this way?

That looks like a video firmware or driver bug to me. I have several suggestions, but none is a sure-fire solution:

- Post more details about your computer's video hardware. Post the computer's make and model, its video chipset(s), and any other relevant details (such as how it's connected to an external monitor, if it's a desktop). This may enable somebody with relevant knowledge to give you more specific advice.
- Try issuing video-related kernel options in GRUB (or whatever boot manager/boot loader you're using). The "nomodeset" option is often recommended, but others that are more specific to your video card may be more appropriate. (Obviously this is possible only if the video problem appears *after* you select the boot option in GRUB.)
- Try installing in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode and then switch the boot mode to EFI by installing an EFI boot loader. (See [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) for information on several and generic installation instructions.) Both types of boot loader can coexist on one system, so it's possible to hobble along for a while with a BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode installation while you test your EFI boot loaders and related options.
- Adjust your boot loader's EFI video mode. There are GRUB commands for doing this, but I don't recall what they are offhand. (You'd need to adjust `grub.cfg` on your installation medium to change the boot mode.) In [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) you'd use the `resolution` option in `refind.conf` -- but of course you'll only be able to do this if you switch to rEFInd. Using rEFInd is relatively easy to do once Linux is installed, but getting rEFInd to boot the Ubuntu installer is much trickier.
- Try using another monitor, at least for installation. If your computer is a laptop, many of them do support external monitors, so you could try plugging one in temporarily.